# password limitations in SQL Server and MySql

Tags: mysql, database, security, passwords

Does MySql 5.1 and SQL Server 2008 (Web edition, Standard) have any functional password limitations other than length limits? Are metacharacters in any form a bad idea to use, like bang, pipe, hash, any slash, carrot, and so on?

I know that MySql 5.1 has a password length limitation of 16 characters that is hardcoded, but I was wondering, are any metacharacters (i.e. non alphanumerics) a bad idea to use? And is this true in SQL Server 2008 Web edition, Standard?

So specifically: can symbols like:

/`~>:}{[]^ be used successfully?

I would hope it doesn't matter to the database, but I don't understand enough about password storage in enterprise database systems yet to know for sure, and I was looking for confirmation or an explanation.

Comment: asteroid: thanks for the kind words. I guess, well, if you don't get a better answer, it'd be cool if you could mark mine down as "accepted"

TIA, roland

Comment: i had a password with a carrot `^` in it and it accepted the password but wouldn't accept it in a connection string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 mysql> create user test identified by '/`~>:}{[]^';
 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)
```

yes - you can actually login now with this command line:

```
 C:\Documents and Settings\rbouman2>mysql -utest -h127.0.0.1 -P3351 -p
 Enter password: **********
```

I tried entering the password directly after -p, but that didn't work for windows - it thinks i want to invoke `more` if I do that. but I am 100% sure that's on the windows shell. MySQL itself feels this is a valid password.

Comment: succinct and incredibly helpful. thank you! I wonder if anyone knows about this for MSSQL..

Comment: @Roland, So what's the actual password limit for MySQL server?

Comment: @Pacerier as long as you use a clean method (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assigning-passwords.html) to assign the password (i.e. not update the mysql.user table directly), I don't think there is any limit, since MySQL stores a hash rather than the actual password.

Answer (score 5):

All these characters are good in SQL Server passwords, but the docs to back it up are sketchy.

The MSDN documentation [on SQL Server password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161962.aspx) strength implies that any symbol including whitespace characters is allowed in SQL Server passwords, but if it contains white space it must be delimited in T-SQL statements.

> Microsoft SQL Server passwords can contain up to 128 characters, including letters, symbols, and digits. Because logins, user names, roles, and passwords are frequently used in Transact-SQL statements, certain symbols must be enclosed by double quotation marks (") or square brackets ([ ]). Use these delimiters in Transact-SQL statements when the SQL Server login, user, role, or password has the following characteristics:
>
> - Contains or starts with a space character.
> - Starts with the $ or @ character.

The MSDN documentation [on password policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161959.aspx) explicitly confirms the following characters are allowed: ! $ # %

And, as you'd already know, the same documentation strongly encourages that you use passwords which are "as long and complex as possible."

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it's the backslash `\` and the single quote `'` that you'll want to avoid in a MySQL password. From my tests, the following special characters appear to be fine to use:

```
!@#$%^&*:./?=+-_[]{}()<>
```

Also, 32-character passwords seem to be okay to use, too.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out, even though MYSQL may work, your php/http daemon/.htaccess may do some wierdness to the req's before passing them along, I had a password with ( $ and ! in it, and it did NOT work from php-mysql based web page, but DID work from the console... 8 character password. $db_pass = "($JlKl1!";
And what do you know, it fails.
change the password to "test" . and bam, it works.
Change the password to something ridiculously long, (and entirely devoid of "$" or "!" or "(" ) and it also worked.